# How to access Failed Hangfire Jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asynchronous, hangfire

I am currently working on EmailNotification module in which i have started using hangfire. The only issue is after trying 10 times, if hangfire fails to (schedule job) email in my case, there is not way i can find to get updates regarding that via code.

I know of the fact, i can access hangfire - dashboard by configuring hangfire  as below:

```
public void ConfigureHangfire(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = AutofacConfig.RegisterBackgroundJobComponents();
    var sqlOptions = new SqlServerStorageOptions
    {
        PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = Config.CreateHangfireSchema
    };
    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("hangfire", sqlOptions);
    Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(container);
    var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions() {Queues = new[] {"emails"}};
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer(options);
}
```

But the issue is i am not able to find a way to access failed job programmatically. I wonder if anyone has come across this issue, would like to know details.

Comment: Try here: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html  Look for "Can we create a custom exception handler".  Maybe this will help.  i didn't make this an answer, cause I'm not sure.

Comment: Logic to access failed jobs based on custom exception, i am not sure if i like that idea. However, i am looking into it - if i find something handy - will update here - Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can use Hangfire Job Filters for this. Job filter allows you to extend functionality of hangfire, and you can do many interesing things with them
(See the official documentation [here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/extensibility/using-job-filters.html) for more details)

Create a class that extends from `JobFilterAttribute`

And then implement `IElectStateFilter` interface. This interface provides you with a method, `OnStateElection` which is called when the current state of the job is being changed to the specified candidate state, say `FailedState`.

```
public class MyCustomFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IElectStateFilter
{
    public void IElectStateFilter.OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        var failedState = context.CandidateState as FailedState;
        if (failedState != null)
        {
            //Job has failed
            //Job ID => context.BackgroundJob.Id,
            //Exception => failedState.Exception
        }
    }
}
```

And then, register this attribute -

```
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new MyCustomFiler());
```

If you need to capture event, after the state is applied, you can implement `IApplyStateFilter` instead.

Comment: Thanks  - That worked!! The only thing is it's async so i wouldn't know instantly what to display on UI - but i guess, for now i am just using three different states like - IN PROGRESS - FINISHED - FAILED - till i get a confirmation of Finished or Failed, i will just use IN PROGRESS as status for that job!!

Comment: With hangfire 1.6.x I experienced that `OnStateElection` would say `failed` even though the retry count was not fully exhausted yet. Not sure whether that is by design, but for my purpose (notify when actually failed and no more retries) the `IApplyStateFilter` did it.